Issue with Using Isolation Forest for Anomaly Detection in Accord.NET: Missing Namespace
enter image description here
I'm trying to implement anomaly detection in my C# application using the Accord.NET library, specifically with the Isolation Forest algorithm. However, I'm encountering an error indicating that the Accord.MachineLearning.AnomalyDetection namespace does not exist.
\<PackageReference Include="Accord.MachineLearning" Version="3.8.0" /\>

\<PackageReference Include="Accord.Math" Version="3.8.0" /\>

\<PackageReference Include="Accord.Statistics" Version="3.8.0" /\>

\<PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="33.0.1" /\>

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AnomalyDetection' does not exist in the namespace 'Accord.MachineLearning' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using CVAnomalyDetection.Models;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private List<CsvData> _csvData;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                _csvData = csv.GetRecords<CsvData>().ToList();
            }
            return View("Index", _csvData);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Predict()
    {
        var anomalies = DetectAnomalies(_csvData);
        return View("AnomalyResults", anomalies);
    }

    private List<CsvData> DetectAnomalies(List<CsvData> data)
    {
        // One-hot encode categorical columns
        var uniqueValuesProductCategory = data.Select(x => x.ProductCategory).Distinct().ToList();
        var uniqueValuesCustomerRegion = data.Select(x => x.CustomerRegion).Distinct().ToList();
        var uniqueValuesPaymentMethod = data.Select(x => x.PaymentMethod).Distinct().ToList();

        // Create the input data array for anomaly detection
        var combinedData = new List<double[]>();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            var features = new List<double>();

            // One-hot encoding for ProductCategory
            foreach (var value in uniqueValuesProductCategory)
            {
                features.Add(value == item.ProductCategory ? 1.0 : 0.0);
            }

            // One-hot encoding for CustomerRegion
            foreach (var value in uniqueValuesCustomerRegion)
            {
                features.Add(value == item.CustomerRegion ? 1.0 : 0.0);
            }

            // One-hot encoding for PaymentMethod
            foreach (var value in uniqueValuesPaymentMethod)
            {
                features.Add(value == item.PaymentMethod ? 1.0 : 0.0);
            }

            combinedData.Add(features.ToArray());
        }

        // Initialize the Isolation Forest
        var isolationForest = new Accord.MachineLearning.IsolationForest()
        {
            NumberOfTrees = 100,
            Contamination = 0.05 // Adjust based on your needs
        };

        // Train the Isolation Forest model with the combined data
        isolationForest.Learn(combinedData.ToArray());

        // Predict anomalies
        var predictions = isolationForest.Decide(combinedData.ToArray());

        // Find and return the actual anomalous records
        return data.Where((d, index) => predictions[index] == -1).ToList(); // -1 indicates an anomaly
    }


    private double EuclideanDistance(double[] a, double[] b)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(a.Zip(b, (x, y) => Math.Pow(x - y, 2)).Sum());
    }
}


Welcome to SO; please do not post images of code or error messages - see how to create a [mre].

Accord does not have such class. I suggest to try ML.NET.
Here is ML.NET tutorial for anomaly detection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sales-anomaly-detection
